# How to get Isascending in c#

Tags: c#

I have a list of point object where point class has two properties X and Y. So I have a object which looks like this

{1,2}
{2,3}
{3,4}    so here in the above elements as you see the X value is increasing from 1-2-3 so I need a method which returns TRUE for this.

if I have a other object say 
{1,2}
{3,2}
{2,1}   here X is not increasing nor decreasing sequentially and hence the method should return false as X goes from 1-3-2.
Can I achieve this in LINQ or what would be the better way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't indicated how consecutive points with equal values of X should be treated. Assuming you consider {1,…},{2,…},{2,…},{3,…} a match, you can write this:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count - 1).All(i => list[i].X <= list[i + 1].X)
```

If they must be strictly increasing, use `<` instead `<=`.

Comment: I need to consider all the points which I will have in the list

Comment: I can't find documentation on MSDN for the `Sequence` method. Could you provide a link?

Comment: I was using the sequenceequal in list and that works fine. Thanks Marcelo for giving me a valuable suggestion.

Comment: List.SequenceEqual(List.OrderBy(c => c.Xvalue))

Comment: I think Marcelo's solution is better, because it's not needed and therefore not efficient to sort the list just to tell whether it is ascending or not.